# HTTPS & FSO.copyfile

Tags: asp-classic, filesystemobject, file-copying

I have a legacy ASP application that uses FSO (Scripting.FileSystemObjec) to copy a file from the web box to a network share.  Since we have upgraded the server to HTTPS, the file copy is slower.  Can I attribute this to the HTTPS upgrade or some other factors??

AHIA,
LarryR...

Comment: It got nothing to do with the HTTPS, more likely it's due to upgrading the server itself (e.g. Windows 2008 Server) or installing patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTPS is used for the communication between client (browser) and the webserver.

as you copy your file from the webserver to another server https is not used for that...